# admin.peers shows peer info (local and public ip). Is this cause for concern?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, security, enode

I'm connecting to a private blockchain network over the internet using geth.

In the console of geth if you run admin.peers it lists both:
local_address(internal ip)
remote_address(external ip)

I have RPC access off, Im only running the http locally for commands.

In an effort to conceal more info I ran geth like this:

`geth --http --http.port "8085" --port 30303 --datadir <path> --networkid <id> --nodiscover console --nat extip:<ext_ip>`

and then ran `admin.nodeInfo.enr` to get a hash that doesnt show my ip.
ex: `"enr:-<hash>"`
versus enode which follows this format: `enode://<hash>@<external_ip>:30303?discport=0`

but after connecting multiple nodes I realized that I can run `admin.peers` and the ip info is visible for each node.

I'm concerned about connecting to peers that I may not trust. This defeats part of the 'trustless' portion. Is this not really a concern? It seems too revealing to give external and local IPs to a group of people.

I tried to run a tor config, but wasn't able to get it running correctly (Im not familiar with it or proxying in general). Should I look more into running a tor proxy? or Proxiv? or VPN? Or would a standard firewall be sufficient? And could anyone provide links/tutorials to get this done?

*Sidenote: Im running my internal network through a firewall with port forwarding. I was able to connect my 2 local node through local network and through external network. I'm not sure if I setup the config for tor correctly given the extra config needed.*